# Как перевести Badge: знак / награда / значок / медалька

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

"badges" ближе к наградам — знакам *отличия* (например, медаль «За усердие при выполнении задач инженерного обеспечения»), нежели к знакам *различия* (погон).

Другие варианты перевода badge: значок (не знак!) (нагрудный для бойскаутов -- значок орла-разведчика), медальон (на шею для римских легионеров), медаль (Школьная Золотая медаль). Упомяну не подходящие варианты тоже: орден («За заслуги перед Отечеством»), эмблема (☭, ☮, ☯ - указывает на принадлежность), жетон (на метро).

Общая идея — `награда`.

- bronze badges: бронзовые награды
- silver badges: серебряные награды
- earned badges: заслуженные награды
- Tag Badges: Тематически Награды
- Question Badges: Награды за Вопросы
- Answer Badges: Награды за Ответы
- Moderation Badges: Награды за Модерацию
- Badges are bits of digital flair that you get when you participate in especially helpful ways: Награда — цифровой медальон, вручаемый за заслуги перед сообществом.

В некоторых случая можно использовать более специфичные медаль, значок:

- Gold Badge: золотая медаль (за ответы в `[X]` метке/теге)
- Taxonomist badge: значок Таксономиста(Классификатора) (как пионерский значок)

«Значок» везде использовать вместо «награда» плохо, потому что не достаточно сильно идея награды/поощрения передаётся. Слово «награда» хорошо передаёт идею награды, но оно может быть не достаточно специфичным (слишком эфемерно, телесности не хватает).

Назначение `badges` — указывать, какое поведение является желательным на сайте.

badges можно заменить единственным словом — «медалька»:

```
 Опосля дождя в четверг
 Дам ишо медальку сверх,
 Только ты уж постарайся,
 Чтоб народ меня не сверг!..

 Генерал

 Ишь, медаль!.. Большая честь!..
 У меня наград не счесть:
 Весь обвешанный, как елка,
 На спине — и то их шесть!.
```

Леонид Филатов. «Про Федота-стрельца. СКАЗКА ДЛЯ ТЕАТРА  (По мотивам русского фольклора)»

`медалька` — присутствует как идея награды так и телесность характерные для слова значок.
`медалька` напоминает, что не нужно слишко серьёзно к виртуальным достижениям относится — создаёт "правильную" атмосферу.

`медалька` — подсказывает что это специальное слово на сайте — слэнг — в отличии от просто медали, награды, знака, значка, которые имеют устоявшиеся значения вне сайта (и не совсем подходящие внутри сайта).

Comment: Еще пришло в голову: «достижения». По сути дела это самые обычные ачивки, используемые во многих играх или игрофицированных сервисах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Выбранный ответ*.

"Badge" нужно перевести как «Знак»

---

*Остальные варианты*.

- "Badge" нужно перевести как «Значок».
- Можно пойти альтернативным путем:

  - badge - награда
  - gold badge   - орден
  - silver badge - медаль
  - bronze badge - значок
- "Badge" нужно перевести как «Награда».
- "Badge" нужно перевести как «Медалька».

Answer (score 2):

пусть и поздно, но добавлю идею на (возможное) будущее:

- бронзовый значок
- серебрянная медаль
- золотой орден

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, почему "значок", а не "знак"?

Comment: окончание цепочки «орден — медаль» у меня ассоциируется скорее со «значком», нежели со «знаком».

Answer (score 1):

Вариант «Награда» считаю самым подходящим. Он достаточно формален, имеет нужные отенки смысла, хорошо переводится в словосочетаниях вроде "bronze badge".

«Знак» у меня вызывает ассоциации с дорожными знаками, а  «Значок» - с пионерией. Если объективно - то эти слова не ассоциируются с идеей поощрения или награды за одобряемое и общественно-полезное действие.

Comment: Поздно. Основная терминология уже устаканилась. Эта охапка постов про перевод перенесена со старой Меты Хэшкода в связи с ее закрытием.

Comment: Эти посты были созданы на старой Мете ХэшКода в переходный период, когда мы начинали переезжать с ХэшКода на StackOverflow. Работы по правке перевода все еще ведутся, поэтому посты нужны хотя бы в справочных целях.

Comment: @Nofate ладно, отправил заявку на вступление в команду переводчиков.

Comment: Пожалуйста, посмотрите на [эту развернутую дискуссию по данной теме](http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/3195/).